# Changing Document Visibility in Google Document List API

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

does someone knows how can I change a doc visibility using Google Document List API?

I'd like to change from private to other visibility (all users in domain can see).

Comment: I'm not trying to add ACLs, i want to set into one of the visibility types: public, private, visible to domain, etc

Answer (score 0):

With the ACLs you can just add a domain, then it will be visible, for all the users in your domain.

In Java:

```
public static void insertDomainAcl(DocsService client, DocumentListEntry entry) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException{
    client.insert(new URL(entry.getAclFeedLink().getHref()), new AclScope(AclScope.Type.DOMAIN, "domain.com"), new AclRole("reader"));
}
```